# Convert a number enclosed in parentheses (string) to a negative integer (or float) using Python?

Tags: python

In Python, what is the simplest way to convert a number enclosed in parentheses (string) to a negative integer (or float)?

For example, '(4,301)' to -4301, as commonly encountered in accounting applications.

Comment: I don't know of a built-in way to do it. You can parse the comma-separated integer with [`locale`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th), but you'll need to handle the negativity yourself.

Comment: Strange, there is `locale.currency` to go the other way, but you want the inverse of that which I can't seem to find ..  same question was asked here already and no satisfactory answers  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8421922/674039

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
my_str = "(4,301)"
num = -int(my_str.translate(None,"(),"))
```

Comment: Wow, translate is awesome!

Comment: Thanks, this led me to `int('(4,301)'.replace('(','-').translate(None,'), '))` which was enough for my purposes.

Comment: Hi there. this answer assumes that i'm only going to deal with negative numbers. Any solution for when I'm not sure whether it'll be negative or positive ?

Comment: @PedroBraz: It doesn't assume that. If there are no parentheses, it just won't translate any, and will just remove any commas.

Comment: true say, but the minus is outside the function, thus it'll be negative even though parenthesis abscense. I mean, i know a if will solve that, I was just looking for a clean solution. Thanks a lot for the answers !

Comment: @PedroBraz: OK, you may have misunderstood the premise of the question, which deals with numbers presented in the accounting convention where negative numbers are shown enclosed in parentheses, and not with a minus sign. There is no "function" here - if your number has a minus sign, then you just have an incorrectly formatted number, at least in terms of the format that this question is asking about. For a number like `-4,301`, just get rid of the comma and convert it with `Int()`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, I think PedroBraz is pointing out that if you set my_str to '4,301', num will be set to -4301. It's clear from a comment above that this is not the behavior silvernightstar wants, and it's probably not the behavior Pedro Braz wants either (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718648/convert-a-number-enclosed-in-parentheses-string-to-a-negative-integer-or-floa#comment24153742_16718742).

Comment: @PedroBraz, in case you're still interested, I think silvernightstar's comment above gives the kind of clean solution you're looking for (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718648/convert-a-number-enclosed-in-parentheses-string-to-a-negative-integer-or-floa#comment24153742_16718742).

Answer (score 8):

Since you are reading from a system that put in thousands separators, it's worth mentioning that we are not using them the same way all around the world, which is why you should consider using a locale system. Consider:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )
my_str = "(4,301)"
result = -locale.atoi(my_str.translate(None,"()"))
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I am in Denmark, and experience all kinds of crap due to "interesting" locales...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming just removing the `,` is safe enough, and you may wish to apply the same function to values that may contain negative numbers or not, then:

```
import re
print float(re.sub(r'^\((.*?)\)$', r'-\1', a).replace(',',''))
```

You could then couple that with using `locale` as other answers have shown, eg:

```
import locale, re

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8')
print locale.atof(re.sub('^\((.*?)\)$', r'-\1', a))
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python 3.6, and also handles '-' as 0, and strips excess empty spaces:

```
def clean_num(num_string):
    bad_chars = '(),-'
    translator = str.maketrans('', '', bad_chars)
    clean_digits = num_string.translate(translator).strip()

    if clean_digits == '':
        return 0
    elif '(' in num_string:
        return -float(clean_digits)
    else:
        return float(clean_digits)
```

Comment: Worked for me !! we can update bad_chars with additional bad charcs to get desired result

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to handle positive numbers as well as negative, which is missing from many of the answers thus far. I'm going to add a bit to the [answer from mogul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718893/5987).

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, '')
my_str = '( 4,301 )'
positive = my_str.translate(None, '()')
result = locale.atoi(positive) if positive == my_str else -locale.atoi(positive)
```

Answer (score 2):

For localized numbers, I use this:

```
def clean_number(text):
    import locale
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "Portuguese_Brazil.1252")
    tbl = str.maketrans('(', '-', 'R$ )')
    return locale.atof(text.translate(tbl))
```

Works with Python 3.8.
The first parenthesis is replaced with the minus sign, the second is removed.
Also removes spaces and the monetary sign.

Answer (score 0):

This code could be a little bit longer, but straight forward and easy to maintain

```
from pyparsing import Word, nums, OneOrMore

integer = Word(nums)

text = "blah blah (4,301) blah blah " 

parser = OneOrMore(integer)

iterator = parser.scanString( text )

try:
    while True:
        part1 =  iterator.next()
        part2 =  iterator.next()
except:
    x =  part1[0][0][0] + '.' +part2[0][0][0]
    print -float(x)
```

**Produces**: `-4.301`

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16718742) is specific to Python 2. I tried editing it, but the queue is full.

For `my_str = "(4,301)"`, the top answer advises:

```
num = -int(my_str.translate(None,"(),"))
```

For Python 3, you would instead use one of the following:

```
translate_table = dict({ord(i): None for i in '(),'})
num = -int(my_str.translate(translate_table))
```

or, more simply

```
num = -int(my_str.translate({ord(i): None for i in "(),"}))
```

---

If you're curious, the change is necessary for two reasons:

1. [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) now expects a single argument.
2. The `str` type contains Unicode. This is why each key in the dictionary is first passed to [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord): this function accepts a given Unicode character and returns the Unicode code point for it:

   ```
    >>> ord('(')
    40
   ```