# How to read '$1,234.56' as 1234.56

Tags: python, python-3.x, currency

I've looked through the 'currency' threads, but they're all for going the other way.  I'm reading financial data that comes in as $1,234.56 &c, with everything a string.  I split the input line, and want to convert the value item to float for add/subtract (I'm mot worried about roundoff error).  Naturally, the float() throws an error.

I could write a function to call as 'amount = float(num(value_string)), but woder if there's a "dollar_string_to_float()" function in one of the 32,000 Python modules.

Comment: Take a look here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is slightly different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python), but I'm not sure.

Anyway, the code from the afformentioned question just need one function change from `Decimal` to `Float` and the removal of the Decimal import.

As you requested, the code is in a `dollar_string_to_float` function:

```
>>> from re import sub

>>> def dollar_string_to_float(s):
        return float(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', money))


>>> money = '$1,234.56'
>>> print dollar_string_to_float(money)
1234.56
```

Comment: @ZZMike I really doubt this function would be placed in any of the standard libs, but that doesn't make it less useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the regular expressions module. You can compile a pattern that matches your dollars/cents format and extract the floating-point number from it.

Comment: Unless you are going to add to it, this answer should probably be a comment.