# Float string number to float with 2 decimals?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function

```
def float_():
    price_data = {}
    str_num = '3.505,32'
    price_data['price'] = float(str_num.replace('.','').replace(',','.'))
    price_data['currency'] = 'USD'
    return price_data
```

is there any other way of achieving this float result ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your current approach.

Comment: @MatheusPortela it's a little bit different imo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`locale.atof`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html), as indicated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python), which abstracts things such as the decimal punctuation and thousands separator:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR') # Set to the proper language/country

def float_():
    price_data = {}
    str_num = '3.505,32'
    price_data['price'] = locale.atof(str_num)
    price_data['currency'] = 'USD'
    return price_data
```