# Python3 - Importing a price (£) from excel and converting it into an integer

Tags: python, excel, string, parsing

so I am importing (row[3]) from excel which prints the prices set on the spreadsheet but I'm trying to calculate all the prices and find their average. I have them totalled up but I can't     `print(row[3])/100*15)`     because the row is not defined as an integer because it has a '£' sign. Anyone have an idea how I can get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a currency string to a floating point number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python)

Comment: Yeah I saw this but he's assigning the value to a variable whereas I'm trying to convert it directly from the row

Comment: How is `row[3]` different to the "variable" they're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the symbol with an empty space, and then convert the string to a float. For example `float('34$56'.replace('$',''))` will return `3456.0` no matter where the $ is.