# creating a function to read file and create dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to read from a file that contains elements that I am going to edit and store in a dictionary. However I am facing this error when running the code

```
def read_file(filename):
infile = open(filename, 'r')
elements = {}
for line in infile:
    infile.readline()
    words = line.split(';')
    for i in range(len(words)):
        element = words[i].split('-')[0].upper().strip()
        density = words[i].split('-')[1].strip().replace(',', '')
        elements[element] = float(density)
return elements


read_file('atm_moon.txt')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "atm_moon.py", line 14, in <module>
read_file('atm_moon.txt')
File "atm_moon.py", line 9, in read_file
density = words[i].split('-')[1].strip().replace(',', '')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

the file looks like this:
https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/IN1900/h20/ressurser/live_programmering/atm_moon.txt

Comment: ```Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):``` doesn't have any ```;```. So ```split``` will keep it as it is. So your list only have 1 value

Comment: I moved' infile.readline()' outside of the for-loop, and it all worked out! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert or anything much in Python, but here's what I think/found:
The first line is a special case that doesn't work with the rest of the code to begin with (no "-" or ";" in it).
You can just take the first line as header with `readline()`, thus removing it from the rest of the read in text:

```
elements = {}
header = infile.readline().rstrip()
elements["header"] = header
```

Then when going through the list of elements and their densities:

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    element, density = words[i].split('-')
    elements[element.strip()] = float(density.strip().replace(',', ''))
```

You can just create two variables `element` and `density` with one `split` function

```
element, density = words[i].split('-')
```

since splitting it beforehand from `;` and then at `-` leaves just two variables anyway.
Sidenote: if you know how many elements/variables a function creates/returns when you use it, you can assign that many variables as that function's return values, i.e:

```
var1, var2, ..., varN = function_that_returns_N_variables(foo)
```

Then when adding them to the dict you simultaneously `strip()`, `replace()` and/or convert with `float()` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line:

```
Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):
```

Doesn't have any semi colons. So `split` will leave the string untouched. So there is only 1 element in the list. When you try to fetch `[1]`, the list element doesn't exists and it raises an error.

1 work around is to check if the list's length is greater than 1.

```
for line in infile:
    words = line.strip("\n").split(';')
    if len(words)>1:
        for i in words:
            a,b=i.strip().split('-')

            elements[a]=float(Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', b)))
```

References:
[How do I convert a currency string to a floating point number in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your first line: `Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):` doesn't have `-` char, so `words[i].split('-')` will generate list of single element here.

```
>>> "Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):".split("-")
['Estimated Composition (night, particles per cubic cm):']
```

and you can't get element with index `1` from it.

I would suggest to skip all words without `-`. I also think that you don't need line `infile.readline()` so I would rewrite loop as follows

```
for line in infile:
    words = line.split(';')
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if "-" not in words[i]:
           continue
        element = words[i].split('-')[0].upper().strip()
        density = words[i].split('-')[1].strip().replace(',', '')
        elements[element] = float(density)
return elements
```